# Acessing dictionary inside dictionary and assigning it to a variable

Tags: swift, xcode, dictionary, mapkit, latitude-longitude

I am trying to use a dictionary to store the information about harbours, it works without the "[ ]" in the dict but when I am trying to store more information inside and trying to get the coordinates and other information it fails on me.

```
let dict = [
        "Holmsbu": ["cord":CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(59.5, 10.4)],
        "Kragerø": ["cord":CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(59.1, 10.4)],
        "Risør": ["cord":CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(59.2, 10.4)],
        "Strömstad": ["cord":CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(59.3, 10.4)]]
    
    for havner in dict {
        map.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionMake(havner.value, MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1)), animated: true)
        let mk = MKPointAnnotation()
        mk.coordinate = havner.value
        mk.title = havner.key
        map.addAnnotation(mk)
        }
    }
```

I am trying to do this

```
 let dict = ["Holmsbu": ["cord":CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(59.5, 10.4), "power": "yes", "description":"DESCRIPTION HERE"]
```

And accessing the Description part of the dictionary something like this:

```
mk.subtitle = havner.description
```

Errors:

> Cannot convert value of type '[String : CLLocationCoordinate2D]' to expected arg
>
> Cannot assign value of type '[String : CLLocationCoordinate2D]' to type 'CLLocationCoordinate2D'

Answer (score 0):

`value` is a dictionary of type `[String : CLLocationCoordinate2D]`

You have to get the value for key `cord`, the type cast is only needed if there are more key-value pairs.

```
for havner in dict {
    map.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionMake(havner.value, MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1)), animated: true)
    let mk = MKPointAnnotation()
    mk.coordinate = havner.value["cord"]! // as! CLLocationCoordinate2D
    mk.title = havner.key
    map.addAnnotation(mk)
    }
}
```

and

```
mk.subtitle = havner.value["description"] as! String
```

I recommend to use a struct

```
struct Havner {
    let name : String
    let coordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2D
    let description : String
}
```

and an array of `Havner`, then you can use dot syntax like `havner.description`

Comment: But I am going to add many thousand, is this the most effective way then?

Comment: A (more specific) struct is always more efficient than a (less specific) dictionary. Still more efficient is to store the harbor information in a json or property list file and decode it into the struct with `Decodable`